# StateElementReferenceException python

Tags: python, for-loop, selenium-webdriver

I'm using chrome driver to extract data.

I'm stuck at one point: I need to iterate over an entire list (all elements). The first time it works, and I'm able to download one file.

For the second iteration, it shows up a mistake of "StaleElementReferenceException with an element is not attached to the page document".

The code looks something like this:

```py
for elem in browser.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/form[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/select/option'):
  elem.click()
  sleep(2)
  for ele in browser.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/form[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/select/option'):
    ele.click()
```

How should I change my loop to get over this problem? (the problem is at ele.click)

Comment: What code you use? Can you provide it to question?

Comment: @Yeheshuah yes but it is too long